# Не видит внешюю библиотеку в JARe

Tags: java, jar, lib

Хочу скомпилировать проект в JAR-ник. Все бы ничего, да только после компиляции при попытке запуска на сервере по каким-то причинам внешняя библиотека не находится.

Вот на что собственно он ругается:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/json/simple/JSONObject
>           at ru.edu.hse.masitnikov.t_service.httpserver.userthreads.UserThread.run(UserThread.java:26)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 2 more

Вот файл манифеста:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: json-simple-1.1.1.jar
Main-Class: ru.edu.hse.masitnikov.t_service.httpserver.main
```

А вот структура JAR-ника:

[image: Структура JAR-файла]

Comment: Я не уверен, что java умеет читать jar внутри jar. У меня не очень большой опыт работы с внутренней кухней, но подобная проблема на продакшене решается разархивированием и включением всех скопилированных файлов в один uberjar (с помощью maven shade plugin).

Comment: @Etki, уже задумывался так и сделать, но решил тут уточнить, авось есть какие то более интересные методы

Comment: @Etki Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа, так как он может помочь решить проблему.

Comment: Один jar засовывать внутрь другого нельзя. На счёт "разобрать" jar на классы, и собрать из этого новый вместе со своими классами, я бы рекомендовал избегать такой практики, т.к. могту быть различные лицензионные органичения на разные библиотеки, исполузуемые в вашей программе. Если вашему проекту необходимы внешние библиотеки, то их просто кладут в папку собранного проекта или специальную папку LIB и подключают через CLASSPATH. Это общепринятая практика.